# No way to regenerate Bluemix service credentials

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, cloudant

If I go to any IBM Cloud aka Bluemix service, say Cloudant service instance > Service Credentials, there is a new credential button. But it always generates the same credentials (same password etc).

I have tried multiple ways but result is always same, for eg,

- Delete the existing credential and try to create a new one
- Create a new one while a credential already exists
- Delete the existing credential and Create a new one with same name
- Delete the existing credential and Create a new one with a different name etc

Could anybody please let me know how to get new password or set it to whatever we want ? This is an important requirement in cases like compromised passwords etc. Hence the question.

Comment: Is this on a shared account or enterprise? And when was the Cloudant service created?

Comment: Afaik you can't change this credential though the UI; but you can manage (add/grant permissions/delete) other credentials that you've created within each database by opening the service console.You might have to contact support. Keep in mind your apps should always use API keys (which can be used to provided limited access) and not master the credentials.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no option to reset the service credentials that are auto-generated for Cloudant. You can create a new Cloudant instance (with new auto-generated creds and URL) and replicate the data over.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reset the service credentials without creating a new instance and copying over the data.

I recommend generating an API key for your database through Cloudant:

[image: database]

You will be able to fine-tune the permissions and create/revoke API keys as much as you would like.